# What is RPG.SE's relationship with the makers of the Same Page Tool?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that the [same page tool](https://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-same-page-tool/) is promoted a lot by people here. I'm in no way shape or form saying that this is a bad thing; I personally find it very useful myself and I have never had a game where I've run a successful session 0 fall apart due to disputes among the party. However, that said, I've noticed that the one website is promoted a lot here, and I would like to know whether it's just that everyone really finds it useful or if there's any official endorsement by the staff here thus leading to this level of popularity.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no official endorsement or relationship going on.

The Same Page Tool's author was formerly a member of this community. They shared it here, several members found it quite useful and also shared it in other contexts, and it's frequently relevant to a certain type of social issue (expectation mismatch) which we run into a lot.

Members promoting it are doing so for their own reasons (such as because they feel it's useful); there's no ulterior motive there. If you see it promoted here more than elsewhere, that's just because there's been some powerful hearsay about it here.

Comment: formerly? :( that is sad

Comment: I found it before I found this site, but I've referenced it a couple times myself. It's just a good expression of a good idea, and a good concept to have when prepping a game.

Answer (score 14):

Speaking as one of the people who mentions it fairly frequently, I have no formal relationship with bankuei - it was just an epiphany moment when I first saw it and contextualized some previous RPG-related issues I'd had through that lens, and I'm guessing the same is true for others.

Note that the Same Page Tool *itself* is not actually a great answer for most questions; it covers a limited set of variables. It's more the *idea* that people should agree in advance on what game they're playing if at all possible.

Comment: +1 many answers that say "Same Page Tool!" are actually wrong and don't know what the SPT is, and insert a mental image of "complete getting everyone on the same page as to game tone" into its conceptual space; it's much more modest than that.